# Interrupting socket connection

Tags: java, sockets

I have a socket program which is sending text data via PrintWriter(out.write(String str)), on the other side BufferedReader(in.readLine()) is receiving this.

I want to secure my program with some kind 'timeout' if one of clients breaks the connection, but I tested it and during work, when client will be turned off, server is still sending data and there is no interruption nor socket closing.

Same for client, I want to break connection and display info for example "server is not working".
How I can handle this ?

```
// Server
out = new PrintWriter( sock.getOutputStream());
while( true ) {
   this.out.write("Hello");
   this.out.flush();
}

// Client
in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( sock.getInputStream()));
while (true) {
   in.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Set a read timeout on the socket.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is PrintWriter. See [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html):

> Methods in this class never throw I/O exceptions, although some of its
>   constructors may. The client may inquire as to whether any errors have
>   occurred by invoking checkError().

use [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) instead.

Note that java.util.Scanner has the same issue (in case you are using it on the server side)

Answer (score 1):

I just checked and `PrintWriter.checkError()` method helped me with my issue. When client broke connection, method returned true. As says description: `Flushes the stream if it's not closed and checks its error state.`

```
// Server
this.out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
while (true) {
   this.out.write("Hello");
   this.out.flush();
   if(this.out.checkError()){
      //...
   }
}
```